# How to unflatten RDD based on few columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Hi i have RDD in below format (all values are strings)

```
rdd1 = [(g1, p1, t1, e1, i1, v1), 
        (g1, p1, t1, e2, i2, v2), 
        (g1, p1, t1, e3, i3, v3), 
        (g1, p1, t1, e4, i4, v4),
        (g2, p2, t2, e3, i3, v3), 
        (g2, p2, t2, e4, i4, v4)...]
```

I want to transform it and get in below format

```
rdd2 = [(g1, p1, t1, "e1.i1.v1|e2.i2.v2|e3.i3.v3|e4.i4.v4"),
        (g2, p2, t2, "e3.i3.v3|e4.i4.v4")...]
```

So based on g, p and t values, i want to unflatten the RDD and i want to get e.i.v values pipe separated in the same row. You can treat g, p and t as key for resulting tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward, something like this:

```
rdd1
 .map { case (g, p, t, e, i, v) => ((g, p, t), s"$e.$i.$v")}
 .reduceByKey { _ + "|" + _ }
 .map {case ((g, p, t), v) => (g, p, t, v)}
```